# Background color hover animation from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following issue. I have a block and want the background color to have an animation from bottom to top by the hover. Please, let me know where is my trouble? Much appreciate.

```css
.right-block--wrapper {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    padding: 15px 19px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 429px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.right-block--wrapper:before {
    background:#474747;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position:
    absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform:scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    z-index: -1;
}
.right-block--wrapper:hover {
    background: #474747;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-block--wrapper">
     <p>Demo Content</p>               
</div><!-- right-block--wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't applying any styles to the `::before` pseudo element when the `.right-block--wrapper` element is hovered.

I think perhaps you meant to do this:

```css
.right-block--wrapper {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding: 15px 19px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 429px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.right-block--wrapper:before {
  background: #474747;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.right-block--wrapper:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-block--wrapper">
  <p>Demo Content</p>
</div>
<!-- right-block--wrapper -->
```

Comment: Yes, that's great. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'll tick as answered in 5minutes.